# How to change default behavior of Rack::Offline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, browser-cache

I am trying to cache my pages in the views folder. I got this from the rack::Offline page but I can't figure out where I am suppsoe to add the code.

```
offline = Rack::Offline.configure do
  cache "contacts/list." # contacts is the folder in views folder where my list.html.erb file is located
  public_path = Rails.public_path
  Dir[public_path.join("javascripts/*.js")].each do |file|
    cache file.relative_path_from(public_path)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem. Rack::Offline.configure will return an instance of Rack::Offline. But I don't know Rack and how it works...

Answer (score 2):

It goes in your routes.rb file. Some good information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906385/how-to-change-default-behaviour-of-rack-offline/4965702#4965702).